# Angular with Browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I'm new to Browserify and I'm trying to setup a project with it and Angular 1.5.3. I am getting the following error when I view my site:

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module is not a function
```

Stepping through the code I can see that in my line below, angular is an empty object:

```
var angular = require("./../bower_components/angular/angular.js");
```

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');


//the core bundle for our application
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return browserify('app/app.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed angular using npm instead of bower when I started using browserify. Then I was able to say:

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

and it works fine. I believe you can use bower still, but you might need to use debowerify. I'm not certain- too much of the browserify process is still kind of magic to me, and needs unpacking.